# Nested selector of CSS doesnt work in IE8 but works in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Hi The below code works fine in IE6 but not in IE8 may i know what is causing the problem ?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .dataSection {
     font-weight:bold;
     color:#fff;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
     text-align:left;
     background-color:#004E82;
     padding:2px 4px 2px 2px;
  }
  .dataSection.header {
     font-weight:bold;
     color:#fff;
     font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
     text-align:left;
     background-color:#004E82;
     padding:2px 4px 2px 2px;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table class="DataSection">
<tr>
  <td class="header">Summary</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS is wrong, it just seems to work in Internet Explorer 6 because it has a bug whereby it treats `.foo.bar` as `.bar`

You are looking for `.foo .bar`. i.e. "An element with class bar that is a descendent of an element with class foo" as opposed to what you have, which is "An element with both class foo and bar such as `<div class='foo bar'>`".

Comment: It is indeed the last class mentioned.

Comment: … and question edited to remove the comments about guesswork now the question has been updated.